# Master JavaScript Regex Guru Needed For Recursive Filtering

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion, filter

I'm in serious trouble with a JavaScript regex. What I want is "regex only" solution to perform transformations like this :

```
{{ users.name.find(50, "q")|lower }}  ---> lower(users.name.find(50, "q"))
```

I ended up with the following decomposition, and it works great :

```
var m = '{{ users.name.find(50, "q")|lower }}';
var p = m.replace(/{{2}[ ]*([^{}, ]*[^{}]*[^{}, ]+)[ ]*}{2}/g, "$1");
console.log(p);    --->    users.name.find(50, "q")|lower

var k = p.replace(/(.+)(\|{1}(.*))+/g, "$3($1)");
console.log(k);    --->    lower(users.name.find(50, "q"))   --->  OK, it's fine.
```

But now, I want it to work with much complicated filtering like that :

```
var m = '{{ users.name.find(50, "q")|lower|filter(5, 9)|short|encode(true) }}';
```

I'm expecting something like this at the end :

```
console.log(
   m.replace(/MagicalRegexFromHell/g)
   .split(...).join(...)
   .replace(/GuruRegex2/g, 'recursive thing that does not exists $n($n-1)')
   .replace('/OkItsDone/g')
)

---->  encode(short(filter(lower(users.name.find(50, "q")), 5, 9)), true)
```

I've spent hours on it, so please if anybody has a solution using only split() / replace() / regex and join() it would be cool because I'm not able to use branch statements in my code implementation (that's it: no switch, no if etc ...)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
// var p comes from your code
var r = p.split(/|/).reduce(function(txt, f) {
    var par = (f.indexOf("(") + 1) || f.length;
    return f.substring(0, par)
        + (par == f.length ? "(" : "")
        + txt
        + (par == f.length ? ")" : ", ") + f.substring(par);
});
```

I don't think you can apply a regex recursively without a loop.